# biblatex-chicago authordate fullcite problem

Tags: biblatex, citing, chicago-style

The following might be a bug, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a workaround.

I have two bibliography entries with `crossref`, which I need to print using `fullcite` in my document. I do not want to print the main bibliographic entry. I am able to do it without a problem in `biblatex-chicago`. But as soon as I specify `authordate` I get an error. The error only prints in my log when I have the `hyperef` package loaded, but regardless there is an error. The error reads `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.0@Editorzzz:2002} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`

this is mybib.bib

```
@incollection{Lxxx:2002,
    Author = {Nxxx Lxxx},
    Crossref = {Editorzzz:2002},
    Title = {This is a story}}

@incollection{Lyyy:2002,
    Author = {Nyyy Lyyy},
    Crossref = {Editorzzz:2002},
    Title = {This is another story}}

@book{Editorzzz:2002,
    Address = {Durham},
    Booktitle = {A Reader of Something},
    Editor = {Nzzz Editorzzz},
    Publisher = {Duke University Press},
    Title = {A Reader of Something},
    Year = {2002}}
```

This is my preamble tmp.tex

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}


\fullcite{Lxxx:2002}

\fullcite{Lyyy:2002}

\end{document}
```

When I do not specify `authordate` I get this:

> Nxxx Lxxx, “This is a story,” in A Reader of Something, ed. Nzzz Editorzzz (Durham: Duke University Press, 2002)
>
> Nyyy Lyyy, “This is another story,” in Editorzzz, A Reader of Something

Which is fine. But when I specify `authordate` then I get this:

> Nxxx Lxxx. 2002. “This is a story”in Editorzzz 2002
>
> Nyyy Lyyy. 2002. “This is another story”in Editorzzz 2002

A full citation is missing for at least one of them. Is there a workaround? I'm working on a syllabus and I have a lot of cross referenced entries but do not want to print the the reader, or main collection since I'm only including the full citation some entries in the collection.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all: `hyperref` has nothing to do with that, the issue persists even if you don't have `hyperref`.
`\fullcite` essentially prints what would be in the bibliography - and the `authordate` style is defined not to print the full ref.

Answer (score 1):

The cross-referenced parent is printed in the bibliography by default. Since you do not invoke `\printbibliography` references to the parent bibliography item cause the warnings. Normally you can suppress items in the bibliography with the `skipbib` option, but the style ignores its setting. So I'd consider this a bug.

From the `incollection` driver defined in `chicago-authordate.bbx` it is apparent that the text following the `in` string is generated by the command `\bibxrefcite{\thefield{crossref}}`. In `chicago-authordate.cbx`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\bibxrefcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}%\usebibmacro{clearalmostall}} (?)
  {\usebibmacro{cms-in:}%
    \blx@ibidreset% For authordate style
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {}
```

To fix the missing punctuation/whitespace before the `in` string and obtain a "fuller" citation you can redefine this in your preamble with:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\bibxrefcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\newunitpunct% add missing punctuation
   \usebibmacro{cms-in:}%
   \blx@ibidreset%
   \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

To obtain shorter subsequent citations to the parent entry, load `biblatex-chicago` with `citetracker` and make use of the `\ifciteseen` test in `\bibxrefcite`. For example:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\bibxrefcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\newunitpunct% add missing punctuation
   \usebibmacro{cms-in:}%
   \blx@ibidreset%
   \ifciteseen
     {\printnames{labelname}\newunit\printfield{title}}
     {\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

You should get in touch with the `biblatex-chicago` author about the missing punctuation/whitespace and potential for non-existent link targets directly.